# Taking build for production and development is built, but while running FE, the API not working

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have completed taking development and production build for my node server using webpack. My build will be saved in dist/main.js file. When I run "npm start", it runs dist/main.js correctly, express server is listening and mongoDB is connected. But when I start my app and hit login, the api says - Cannot POST /login

I'm new to webpack and looking for a fix in this.

My webpack.config.js is below,

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    target: 'node',
    node: {
      dns: 'mock',
      net: 'mock',
      fs: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      module: 'empty'
      }
  };
```

Package.json scripts will be,

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/main.js",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./src/index.ts --output ./dist/main.js",
    "prod": "webpack --mode production ./src/index.ts --output ./dist/main.js"
  },
```

Actual result i'm getting is,

Request URL: http://localhost:23457/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:23457
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

It fails in the login itself.

I think the dist build is not serving the routes.ts file's API.

Answer (score 0):

> My build will be saved in `dist/main.js`. When I run `npm start`, it runs `node dist/main.js` correctly, express server is listening and mongoDB is connected.

The job of Webpack is to build the files, ie to construct `dist/main.js` based on your source code. Since it runs this script corrrectly, the job of Webpack is done, and Webpack works fine and as expected in your project.

The 404 error originates from your express server. Make sure that your express server can handle POST requests to `/login`, for example with something like:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  // do your stuff here
  // make sure you don't send a 404 here also
});
app.listen(/* ... */)
```

Without having access to your server code, it's impossible to know for sure where your server has a bug. Make sure your express server logs all of the errors and you might know what's wrong yourself, but basically, you should have something that looks like above somewhere in your code, else, your server will respond with a 404 for `/login`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nino Filiu. My server has all the API running perfect, if i run my server without webpack config, it works fine. I think webpack running with only one entry point index.ts, so i have set multiple entry points now in the config and while I run it shows some error in building.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting while building it,                                                        Built at: 04/12/2019 1:05:30 PM
  Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  4.71 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.js
[./node_modules/mongoose/lib sync recursive ^.*\/connection$] ./node_modules/mongoose/lib sync ^.*\/connection$ 222 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/image.ts] 275 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[./src/index.ts] 2.49 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/reportLog.ts] 268 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]